# Assign different public IPs to several instances of same Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, proxy, ip

I made a docker container where I set up python 3.6 and some specific software packages. There, I run an application that connects to a remote API service that has per-IP call-ratio limitations (i.e. it is not possible for an IP to send more than x calls per minute to the API service, otherwise it gets blocked). As a result, I want to use several copies of the same container, each one connecting with a different IP so that I can bypass that problem.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to assign a public IP to a linux container? How can it be done to a docker container?Maybe via proxy?

Comment: This question is actually about programming and development of docker containers. It is not fair what you did, no matter the long experience you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to assign a public IP to a docker container you need to use [Macvlan network driver](https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/) for example:

> Macvlan network driver can be used to assign a MAC address to each container’s virtual network interface, making it appear to be a physical network interface directly connected to the physical network.

This command will create a Macvlan network which bridges with a given physical network interface

```
docker network create -d macvlan -o macvlan_mode=bridge --subnet=172.16.86.0/24 --gateway=172.16.86.1 -o parent=eth0 pub_net
```

Then create a container that will use the above network:

```
docker run --name web_container --net=pub_net --ip=172.16.86.2 --mac-address 25-EE-4E-B5-21-48 -itd nginx
```

Now you have a public facing container running on `172.16.86.2` and sure from the same docker image you can run multiple docker container and assign a public IP to each one.

Comment: Thank you. So, on the eyes of the rest of the world each container instance has a different IP?

Comment: Yes, exactly each container will hold its own public IP